# How can i copy first N elements of a std::map to another map?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, std

I would like to copy first N elements of a std::map to another map. I tried copy_n but failed miserably. How can I achieve that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  map<int,int> Map;
  for ( int i=0;i<10;i++) Map[i]=i*i;
  map<int,int> Map2;
  std::copy_n(Map.begin(), 5,  Map2.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even if you think you failed miserably, please post the relevant parts of your code in your question. Otherwise, there is no way for us to determine how miserably you failed, if at all.

Comment: You'll have to post your `std::copy_n` code so we can figure out why it didn't work.  It should have.

Answer (score 6):

Use `copy_n`? It works as it should:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m1 { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 9 }, { 3, 6 }, { 4, 100 } }, m2;
    std::copy_n(m1.begin(), 2, std::inserter(m2, m2.end()));

    for (auto const & x : m2)
        std::cout << x.first << " => " << x.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z2bwu8d7
This is my code. I am getting `copy_n was not declared in scope`

Comment: @user1159517 What compiler are you using?

Comment: The trick is using `inserter`, `std::copy_n` does not insert elements for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you're constructing the other map from scratch, you can simply pass it the iterators that it needs to the constructor:

```
std::size_t n = ...;

std::map<K, V> m1 = { ... };
std::map<K, V> m2(m1.begin(), std::next(m1.begin(), n));
```

Comment: +1 because it's The Right Way, even though it isn't the Y to the OP's X.

Comment: Nice, but wont the slice of `m1` be iterated twice?

Comment: @pmr Yeah, it will be. Unless it's particularly performance sensitive, however, I wouldn't really worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new map, you can use the range constructor. Inserting into an existing map can be done with range std::map::insert.

```
// copy 3 elements from map source
std::map<K,V>::iterator first = source.begin();
// can also use std::next if available
std::map<K,V>::iterator last = source.begin();
std::advance(last, 3);

std::map<K,V> m1( other.begin(), last);
m1.insert(first, last);
```

std::copy can also be used, but then you must use an std::inserter as output iterator.